# JBoss AS 7.1.1 won't start because of BridgeRepositorySelector

Tags: jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

My JBoss 7.1.1 AS standalone installation has trouble starting up. The exception messege is this:

```
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx51
2M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.se
rver.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.war
ning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.c
onfig=standalone.xml

===============================================================================

11:02:35,115 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
11:02:35,239 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] Failed to define class org.jboss.logmanag
er.log4j.BridgeRepositorySelector in Module "org.jboss.logmanager.log4j:main" fr
om local module loader @53c8b26e (roots: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules): org.j
boss.modules.ModuleLoadError: Error loading module from C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\
modules\org\apache\log4j\main\module.xml
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException.toError(ModuleLoadException.jav
a:78)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1166)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:512)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:
182)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(Con
currentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(Concu
rrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentCl
assLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoad
er.java:120)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) [rt.jar:1.7.0
_02]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
2) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLo
ader.java:327)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.jav
a:391)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.
java:243)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoade
r.java:73)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:
182)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(Con
currentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(Concu
rrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentCl
assLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoad
er.java:120)
        at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:73) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Fi
nal.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1
.7.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:260)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:291)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLS
treamReaderImpl.java:592) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(X
MLStreamReaderImpl.java:1234) [rt.jar:1.7.0_02]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:
539)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java
:287)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java
:242)
        at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.parseModuleInfoFile(LocalModuleLo
ader.java:138)
        at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.findModule(LocalModuleLoader.java
:122)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:275)

        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:222)
        at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.preloadModule(LocalModuleLoader.j
ava:94)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:841)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1181)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPaths(Module.java:1153)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1164)
        ... 26 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logmanager/
log4j/BridgeRepositorySelector
        at org.jboss.as.server.Main.main(Main.java:73)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:260)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:291)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.log4j.BridgeRe
positorySelector from [Module "org.jboss.as.server:main" from local module loade
r @53c8b26e (roots: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:
190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(Con
currentClassLoader.java:468)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(Concu
rrentClassLoader.java:456)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentCl
assLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoad
er.java:120)
        ... 7 more
```

In my installation folder C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\org\jboss\logmanager\log4j\main there is the jboss-logmanager-log4j-1.0.0.GA.jar that contains the class BridgeRepositorySelector. Don't know why and where i get an error.

Any one has an idea of what should i do to fix the problem? And also, does anyone know of what might caused the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer, that somewhat fixed the problem.

I have downloaded a new installation of JBoss7.1.1 and replaced my old `modules` folder with the new one. It work in some, extend, i just need to find all modules added so far to my previous installation and add them in modules so that everything can work again. But still don't know what caused the problem...

Comment: It looks like maybe the dependency was missing on the server's module.xml. `C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\org\jboss\as\server\main`

Comment: @James R. Perkins I noticed that when I undeployed all webapps and then start the server everything would boot up nicely. Is there any case that jboss will complain if i use libraries in my webapps that are used also as modules by JBoss?